# Format input value after Angular2 ngModel is applied

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to create a directive that will format the input value to a currency format.

I am able to do what I have to do on focus and on blur, and in the ngOnInit hook (and any other hook), the input element does not yet have any values applied to it.

How do I "watch" for the input's value, and format it when it's initial value is applied?

Here is my directive:

```
import {
  Input,
  Directive,
  HostListener,
  ElementRef,
  Renderer,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: '[currencyInput]',
  providers: [NgModel],
  host: {
    '(input)': 'onInputChange()'
  }
})
export class CurrencyInputDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() ngModel: number;

  private elem: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private render: Renderer,
    private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe,
    private model: NgModel,
  ) {
    this.elem = el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.elem.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(parseInt(this.elem.value), 'USD', true);
  }

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
  onFocus(value: string) {
    this.elem.value = value.replace(/\,/g, '');
  }

  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
  onBlur(value: string) {
    this.elem.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(parseInt(value), 'USD', true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  ngAfterContentInit() {

    this.model.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if(value) {
        const parsed = parseInt(value.replace('$', ""));
        this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(new CurrencyPipe().transform(parsed, 'USD', true));
      }
    })
  }
```

In your template:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" currencyInput [ngModel]="initModel" name="number"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have tried all lifecycle hooks, and I always get empty value.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to bind to a getter/setter method that will transform the field to the correct format, and then return it back to the original format after it is modified, as per below

typescript:

```
 AnnualRevenue: number;
  get AnnualRevenueFormatted():string{
    return  this.AnnualRevenue !== undefined ?  `$${this.AnnualRevenue.toLocaleString()}`: '$0';
  }

  // strip out all the currency information and apply to Annual Revenue
  set AnnualRevenueFormatted(val: string) {
    const revenueVal = val.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    this.AnnualRevenue = parseInt(revenueVal);
  }
```

and in the component view

```
<input type="text" class="text-input" [(ngModel)]="accountInfo.AnnualRevenueFormatted"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

On my directive I have applied the solution mentioned in this post:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.model.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        if (value) {
            const parsed = parseInt(value.replace('$', ""));
            this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(new CurrencyPipe().transform(parsed, 'USD', true));
        }
    })
}
```

and it works for me.

See my Post : [Directive display ng-model input value as currency in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898808/directive-display-ng-model-input-value-as-currency-in-angular/49916405#49916405)